# If Elif issue / Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I made the following code to scrape some website. A list of product code is itered on research bar with Selenium. If there is no result found (`if driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='search-did-you-mean']"):`) i just clear the research bar to make another search. If there is some results (`elif driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='result-search']"):`) I scrape it

Here is the code :

```
for product in product_list:
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
    inputElement.send_keys(product[0])
    inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    inputElement.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    if driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='search-did-you-mean']"):
        time.sleep(5)
        clearResearch = driver.find_element_by_id("q")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "overley")))
        clearResearch.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
        clearResearch.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    elif driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='result-search']"):
        time.sleep(5)
        item['price'] = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='sale-price']").text
        item['desc'] = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3[class='product-name']").text
        print(item)
```

There is no result for the first product code of the list, so it is cleared and a new code is given. Problem appears with the second item, there is results but my elif condition seems not understand as I get an **Unable to locate element: div[class='search-did-you-mean']** error.

Do you know what is wrong with my code ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is selenium behavior will throw exception if no element found, wrap it in `try-except`

```
first_product = None
try:
    first_product = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='search-did-you-mean']"
except: pass

if first_product:
    .....
```

Comment: Really better this way ! It all works fine now :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_elements_by_css_selector` and check if the returned list has elements in it

```
if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='search-did-you-mean']"):
    #...
elif driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='result-search']"):
    #...
```